# ALTER TABLE ONLY locks the table during changing the default value

Tags: postgresql, migration

I have the table `t_cats` with column `created_at`, with the default value `NOW()`.
So the column is not `nullable` and migration to change the default column value should not lock the table.

But if I use the next migration query, it is.

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY t_cats
ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

According to the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#SQL-ALTERTABLE-PARMS-NAME):

> If `ONLY` is not specified, the table and all its descendant tables (if
> any) are altered. Optionally, `*` can be specified after the table name
> to explicitly indicate that descendant tables are included.

`t_cats` does not have any descending tables. So I really do not understand, why this operation locks the table.

```
ALTER TABLE t_cats
ALTER COLUMN created_at SET DEFAULT NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Code without `ONLY` - does not lock anything.

Comment: Having a `default` value does not necessarily mean the column is not nullable. That is determined by the `NOT NULL` constraint being set on the column. You can have a column with a `default` and insert a `NULL` value if the column constraint is set to `NULL`(which is the default).

Comment: Sure, the `ALTER TABLE` has to take an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, but only for a very short time. Why is that a problem?

Comment: *"Code without ONLY - does not lock anything."* It certainly takes a (very brief) `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock as well. But a new default value does not rewrite the table like you seem to fear, indicated by your (incorrect) remarks about nullability.